# Extending Hibernate context with additional entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a project with two modules. First one (which is main) uses a set of *.hbm.cfg files to map entities. Another one uses annotations to map a few entities. Is it possible to use main project's hibernate session to persist second project's entities?

Answer (score 0):

If your `SessionFactory` only includes entities from the main project - no.

But you can configure it to include entities from both modules. You can even create a kind og "plugin architecture" where each module will contribute its own entities to `Configuration` of a single main `SessionFactory`.